# Compose's "AndroidView"'s factory method doesn't recall when "remember" value change

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I've an `AndroidView` on my UI and I'm creating a custom view class using factory scope. And I've `remember` value above my android view which is changing by user actions.

```
    val isActive = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier
            .align(Alignment.CenterStart)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight(),
        factory = {
            .....
            if (isActive) {
                ...... // DOESN'T RECALL
            }
            .......
            CustomViewClass().rootView
        })

    if (isActive) {
        //WORKS FINE WHEN VALUE CHANGE
    } else {
        //WORKS FINE WHEN VALUE CHANGE
    }
```

In factory scope, I'm trying to use `isActive` value for configuring the AndroidView but it doesn't trigger when `isActive` value changes.

Outside from factory scope, everything works fine.

Is there any way to notify the view or any workaround for this?

```
compose_version = '1.1.1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As given in the [Docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis),
Use `update` to handle state changes.

```
update = { view ->
        // View's been inflated or state read in this block has been updated
        // Add logic here if necessary

        // As selectedItem is read here, AndroidView will recompose
        // whenever the state changes
        // Example of Compose -> View communication
        view.coordinator.selectedItem = selectedItem.value
}
```

**Complete code**

```
// Adds view to Compose
AndroidView(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), // Occupy the max size in the Compose UI tree
    factory = { context ->
        // Creates custom view
        CustomView(context).apply {
            // Sets up listeners for View -> Compose communication
            myView.setOnClickListener {
                selectedItem.value = 1
            }
        }
    },
    update = { view ->
        // View's been inflated or state read in this block has been updated
        // Add logic here if necessary

        // As selectedItem is read here, AndroidView will recompose
        // whenever the state changes
        // Example of Compose -> View communication
        view.coordinator.selectedItem = selectedItem.value
    }
)
```